# Java Operator: |=

Tags: java, operators

I just came across the following line inside some sourcecode.

```
int sequ |= element.sequence
```

What does the operator |= mean ? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: means int sequ = sequ | element.sequence

Comment: Use http://www.symbolhound.com/ for searching something like that, see the [results](http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=%7C%3D+java)

Comment: A list of operators can be found here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=|` is a [*compound assignment operator*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), similar to `+=`, `-=`, `/=`, or `*=`, but with bitwise OR instead.

This is equivalent to:

```
sequ = (int) (sequ | element.sequence);
```

where `|` is the bitwise OR operation, meaning that it independently ORs all bits in the left operand with those in the right operand, to get a result. The cast is not necessary if `element.sequence` is already an `int`.

Note: Your original code wouldn't make sense:

> ```
> int sequ |= element.sequence
> ```

You can't declare it there and then and or it with something else. It would need to have been declared and assigned before, such as in:

```
int sequ = 0; /* or some other value */
sequ |= element.sequence;
```

Comment: @WalterM According to the [Java language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2), `E1 op= E2` *is* `(T) ((E1) op (E2))`, which is pretty much the same thing as what I stated, possibly with a cast to the LHS type. If you were in fact talking about casting to int if element.sequence wasn't int, it would have been nice to leave a less cryptic comment. Also, to answer, "If they really were equivalent, then why would we need both?", why would we need `+=` then, if we can just assign the sum manually?

Answer (score 2):

It is short form for:

```
int sequ  = sequ | element.sequence;
```

Similar to `+=`, `-=` except that it is bitwise OR operator.